# Code iteration really slow, why?

Tags: python, hash, iteration

I was able to write some code with the help of the community here, but I am having a problem where my python runs through the iterations and writting out really really slow as apposed to my other script that does the same exact thing but that one ran super fast, is there anything noticeable in this code that might be causing that?

```
with open('c:/file.sql') as inf, open('c:/file.txt','w') as outf:
    for i in xrange(47):
        inf.next()       

    for line in inf:
        data = line.split(',')
        if len(data) < 15:
            inf.next()
        elif len(data) > 35:      
            hash = data[13]
            select = hash[3:len(hash)-1]
            outf.write(select + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes, it's doing disk I/O. That's terribly slow. Without my crystal ball, I can't see the other script, though.

Comment: Are you deliberately wanting to skip a line where len(data) < 15? Also, `for line in itertools.islice(inf, 47, None):` is IMHO more elegant than forcing `next()`

Comment: And `hash[3:len(hash)-1]` can just be written `hash[3:-1]`

Comment: I am new to this is why I do what one who knows wouldn't >< But thanks for all these tips they sure are helping! And yes I want to skip any line without enough data, because that also skips the line where certain large indexes wont exist, and keep program from crashing because of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

smaller version of your code:

```
from itertools import imap, islice
with open('c:/file.sql') as inf, open('c:/file.txt','w') as outf:
    for line in imap(str.strip, islice(inf, 47, None)):
        data = line.split(',')
        if len(data) > 35:
            hash = data[13]
            select = hash[3:-1]
            outf.write(select+'\n')
```

Comment: For now slicing and striping are lazy

Comment: Doing the `strip` before the `islice` changes the meaning of the program; what if the first couple of lines are a header with a different syntax?

Comment: larsmans the first lines are headers, by different syntax I don't understand what you mean in that context.

Comment: @larsmans, fixed: strip will be applied only for sliced lines. Thanks!

Comment: @BrayanHernandez: I mean that the header have a different format than the lines you're actually looking for. I.e., I'm referring to the syntax of your input file, not of your program.

Answer (score 0):

So taking comments into account... I think this is probably what you want:

```
with open('c:/file.sql') as inf, open('c:/file.txt','w') as outf:
    for line in itertools.islice(inf, 47, None):
        data = line.split(',')
        if len(data) > 35:      
            outf.writeline(data[13][3:-1])
```